# Change and save pdf annotation setting in Okular?

Tags: pdf, okular

In Okular,

1. I add inline notes to a pdf file. I change the default settings for
   inline notes:

   - from default font "Ubuntu 13" to "Ubuntu 6", and
   - from default opacity 100% to opacity 0%.

   But I have to change the settings for every inline note. I wonder if
   it is possible to change the settings and save the change for the
   following inline notes?
2. Also how can I create a inline note without  the box-line boundary?
3. How can I move a existing inline note to another place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Point 1)**

Run Okular with no file supplied and select from the menus, *(you many need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to show the menus),* `Settings->Configure Okular` then select `Annotation` - [image]

then select `Inline Note` and click `Edit`:

[image]

Make your changes and `Apply` them - they should become your defaults.  **N.B.** You can add annotation styles of your own with the `Add` button.

**Point 2)** Not as far as I know.

**Point 3)** To move an annotation, hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, move the mouse pointer on it and then start dragging with the left mouse button.

From your question title you may wish to save your annotations for others to see - with recent versions of okular to do this you need to use `File->Save As` or `File->Export As->Document Archive` otherwise your annotations are private

*Any other questions* - Run okular then press <kbd>F1</kbd> for the manual.