# Old(ish) package has QT3 dependency - my distro doesn't carry it

Tags: debian, compiling, qt

I'm trying to build pdfedit, whose latest version - from 2010 - requires QT 3 development files; yet - I only have QT 4 and up on my distro (Debian testing). Do I have any recourse other than manually downloading, building and installing QT 3 outside the package system?

Comment: you could modify pdfedit's source code so that it builds with QT4.  that'll probably be easier, and certainly do less damage to your system.  Alternatively, you might be able to 'backport' (forwardport?) the old QT3 packages from an earlier version of debian.

Comment: @cas: And do you think this is a trivial change to the pdfedit code? i.e. no more than a find-replace in a few files or something about that difficult?

Comment: I have no idea.  It's probably moderately difficult, which may be why it was abandoned in 2010.  It's almost certainly far less difficult than re-building QT3 for a modern distro.

Comment: another alternative would be to use a modern pdf viewer with editing capabilities.  Okular can do that.  I think evince may be able to edit pdfs now too (not sure, i stopped using evince some time ago).    Otherwise, try here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162037/how-to-edit-pdfs

Comment: Yes, Okular can edit PDFs. I posted a question and answer about this some time ago. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230940/4671

Comment: No, Okular can't edit PDFs. I saw what it can do. You can put arbitrary text on a PDF with Okular.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: ... and I don't mean Latin charset of course. I mean RTL scripts, in the proper direction and glyph order etc.

Comment: @cas: No, evince does not have editing capabilities, at least up to and including version 3.18.2 .

Comment: Forward porting QT3 may be an option, though do you have reason to believe `pdfedit` actually works? if you want to try to forward port it, you might want to either rewrite your question or ask another one.