# Mark copy id on PDF printout

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, printing, cups

I have invoices being sent to our system as PDF files.
From there I have a script that periodically checks directory for files and prints them to CUPS attached network printers (HP LJ 400) via ipp.

Every invoice needs to have 4 copies, so the command used is:

```
lpr -P invoiceprint -# 4 invoice.pdf
```

(invoiceprint is a class consisting of 2 printers, btw)

I can see that on each invoice CUPS is creating 4 print jobs, 1 for each copy.

### How can I superimpose copy number on every copy?

So that I would have each copy of the original file coming out with a number "Copy 1", "Copy 2" etc on it.

Is there any way to send superimposed print information to the printer, or should I merge another PDF with the existing one? If so, which is the best tool to do it, and can I add this with CUPS filtering or do I have to create separate PDFs and send each of them to CUPS separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a utility called pdfstamp, part of libtext-pdf-perl package, which does exactly that -- adds text to existing pdf (as a new layer, apparently).

Found info thanks to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233547/overlay-text-in-pdf-via-command-line), pdfstamp was mentioned in comments.

The only issue is it doesn't seem to understand UTF8, even when using Unicode TTF fonts.