# How to include an image in multiple PDF files at once in Linux?

Tags: scripting, pdf

I have to sign a lot of PDF documents that have a standard layout. My signature would be included on the same place in every pdf file.

That is, I received a lot of PDFs that I have to sign one by one. I would like to automate the task.

Is there any good alternative to do this?

Best regards.

Comment: Since the layout is standard, can you include a image file containing your signature in a template layout. Note that there are other document types than PDF. LaTeX or LibreOffice are worth consideration, especially as they can export to PDF...

Comment: What is the format of the original documents?

Comment: I remember the day, when I extracted the boss's signature from a PDF, and inserted it into another and e-mail it back. Images of hand-written signatures are not worth the paper they are written on. Use electronic (cryptographic) signatures.

Comment: I updated my question with more details. My original documents are in PDF format. I just need to include my signature in each document. The problem is that I have lots od documents.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I agree. Unfortunately, in this case, I need to include my handwritten signature in the documents.

Comment: [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) has a `stamp` command which can do this.  It's probably packaged for whatever distro you're using if you're running Linux.  See [How can I add a signature .png to a PDF in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85873/how-can-i-add-a-signature-png-to-a-pdf-in-linux) which has a few wrapper scripts people have written to do this, and several other methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a signature .png to a PDF in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85873/how-can-i-add-a-signature-png-to-a-pdf-in-linux)

Comment: See also [How can I edit a picture into an existing PDF file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167274/how-can-i-edit-a-picture-into-an-existing-pdf-file) and [How to add a picture onto an existing pdf file?](https://superuser.com/questions/452759/how-to-add-a-picture-onto-an-existing-pdf-file)

Comment: @Zaratruta Oh. If you need to, then you need to, no one can argue with that. However, be prepared, someone will use it for some nefarious purpose, and remember it is not worth the paper it is written on: so when reading such a document, treat at as if the signature is not there.